# If some key is already present in the map then what will happen

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

If some key is already present in the map then what will happen

If some key is already present in the map and we are trying the insert different value with same key then what will happen

Comment: I would expect that the new value you provided would overwrite the old value in the map that was previously associated with that key.

Comment: Please show a [mre], what happens depends on the code you use

Comment: if multiple instances with the same key are needed in the map, then you can use std::multimap and iterate over the keys from std::multimap::lower_bound to std::multimap::upper_bound. I'm not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: This is trivial to look up. See [std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and [std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::operator\[\]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `insert`, `emplace`, `emplace_hint` or `try_emplace`, nothing is changed in the map.

If you assign through `[]` or use `insert_or_assign`, the value you supply replaces the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of a map (and dictionary-like constructs also in other languages) that a "key" must be unique. So indeed it is a relevant question to wonder what happens for recurring "keys" and overwrites or assignment etc.

Using the [] operator for std::map the previous existing value is overwritten. This is the desired standard behavior of a map https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map.

However, as noted in the comments, there other methods like insert/emplace in std::map that have specific other behavior: both are designed to "inserts element(s) into the container [...], if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key." -- meaning that they will NOT overwrite.

There are similar data containers in almost any programming language, e.g. "dict" in python etc.

Comment: Not if you use insert https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: Why keep the wrong answer? This can be confusing. Please remove or edit, at least. The question used the term _"insert"_, so this answer is not correct, though the question is not very clear.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I tried to adapt.

Answer (score -1):

The value that is already in the map will simply get overwritten if you simply assign using `[]` or `insert_or_assign`

I've put below an example of what you can expect

```
int main()
{
    map<string, int> mp = { {"Hello", 1} };
    std::cout << mp["Hello"];
    //outputs 1
    mp["Hello"] = 15;
    std::cout << mp["Hello"];
    //outputs 15
}
```

but if you are using `insert`, `emplace`, `emplace_hint` or `try_emplace` and the value is already inside the map, then nothing will happen to the map.

Comment: Not if you use `insert` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert